# Cognitive Modeling Language (CML) vs Imperative Programming vs Declarative Programming

Tags: imperative-programming

I'm reading this article by John Funge about Cognitive Modeling for Computer Games:   http://www.qrg.northwestern.edu/resources/aigames.org/1999/fungegame99.pdf
And some further detailed reading about it in this URL:
http://www.msci.memphis.edu/~classweb/public_html/comp7990/Spring2000/Wally/Presentation5/tsld014.htm

I'm having a hard time to understand the CML:
I understand it's some kind of mix between Imperative and Declarative programming, I just didn't understand how:

For example the following pseudo-code in Imperative Programming:

> Declare a new List called ExpensiveItemsNames;
>   Foreach Item in Items:
>    If ItemPrice > 100 then
>   Add ItemName to ExpensiveItemsNames

vs the Declarative version: (using SQL)

> SELECT ItemName FROM Items
>   WHERE ItemPrice > 100

What would be the CML version of it?
And how does CML help the programmer? I didn't understand that too.

As well, in the further detailed (as mentioned before - meaning the second link I put) website they also talk about pruning to reduce the space complexity.
While I know what is pruning, I couldn't understand it's relation to CML.  They look like two unrelated things to me at the moment.

Comment: This looks too conceptual for StackOverflow. You might be better off asking on Programmers.

Comment: Ok, i'll do that. Thanks.